# Open ended block production times/lengths

Tags: runtime

Is it possible (with std pallets or custom) to create a block and

- never finalize it (is it truly never, or an upper bound) ?
- keep adding transactions (given the node has available storage)?

This assumes the same node creates additional similarly 'open' blocks along side each other.

If this is possible

- Under what constraints (e.g. chain type, etc.)?
- With what costs/tradeoffs?

If not a first-class citizen, can that property be approximated?

Any examples, tutorials, blogs etc.?

Comment: By open ended do you mean variable and possibly indefinite / infinite ? And by lengths do you mean only time or also total weight and size of the block data?

Comment: I've tried to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add more as come across information:

In general ...[it is not necessary that a parachain even needs to be a blockchain. For example, a parachain just needs to satisfy the two constraints listed above: state transition function and collator node.](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-pdk#cumulus)

- Costs/tradeoffs

  - [Time in the network is measured in (*finalized*?) blocks](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/61b9a4d1a8a9bf39c1d89a8dd02f82785c10860c/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L125). So "time" would stand still.

    - [A session is...measured in block numbers](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/03c2c2fe44b405c4b84561cc2c65e5cf7d2c263a/frame/session/README.md#terminology)
    - [In the optimistic scenario, the latency for this message should be at least two blocks...](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-parachains)
  - [Polkadot block size is a maximum 5MB](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/e6fa871e39bab8ccec27070b3b93a2e5e50ff0a4/runtime/common/src/lib.rs#L112)

    - [More Polkadot limits set out here](https://spec.polkadot.network/#defn-polkadot-block-limits)
    - [Some reasoning here](https://research.web3.foundation/en/latest/polkadot/overview/2-token-economics.html#limits-on-resource-usage)
  - Substrate...

Comment: Where do you gather these from? Can you link to references?

Comment: Added reference.